# How can I print the folder of a relative path in Perl?

Tags: perl, directory

I have a script which takes  a relative path to a folder. Is there any way of getting the name of the folder/directory which is pointed to? If needs be, it could be the absolute path, and I will use regex to strip it.

Say I am executing:

```
/example/a/b/c/d/perl.pl
```

e.g. 1

If they input:

```
../../
```

I want it to be able to return 'b' (or the absolute path up to b, I can write a script to strip it).

e.g.2

If they input:

```
./
```

I want it to be able to return 'd' (or again, the absolute path up to d).

Is there an easy way to do this, as the only way I can think of is counting the number of `../` and using that to do a regex on the absolute path of the file, which takes alot of processing.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's simple - just use [Cwd](https://metacpan.org/module/Cwd) module:

```
use Cwd 'abs_path';
my $abs_path = abs_path($file);
```

Answer (score 2):

Relative to the script being executed (as you requested):

```
use Cwd            qw( realpath );
use File::Basename qw( dirname );

my $script_dir = dirname(realpath($0));
my $abs_path = real_path("$script_dir/$rel_path");
```

Relative to the current work directory:

```
use Cwd qw( realpath );

my $abs_path = realpath($rel_path);
```

In both cases, symlinks are resolved. File::Spec provides functions that don't resolve symlinks if that's what you prefer.

Comment: There is no 'real_path' function in Cwd, there is 'realpath' and it is a synonym for an 'abs_path' :)

Comment: Oops, fixed. I am aware that it is a synonym on some platforms. But I specifically want the functionality of realpath.